# Array data going missing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an array of objects with nested arrays, but data is going missing in the last step:

```js
const args_arr = [];
const options_arr = [];
let options = '';

let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if (i === j) {
      args_arr.push(true);
    } else {
      args_arr.push(false);
    }
  }
  text += args_arr + "<br>";
  options = {
    op1: true,
    op2: false,
    args: ['visible']
  };
  text += JSON.stringify(options) + "<br>";
  options.args.push(args_arr);
  text += JSON.stringify(options) + "<br>";
  options_arr.push(options);

  args_arr.length = 0;
}
text += '<br>' + JSON.stringify(options_arr) + "<br>";

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Everything works as expected, but at the last step where I push options into options_arr the arrays after 'visible' goes missing.

Here's the result:

```
true,false,false,false,false
{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible"]}
{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible",[true,false,false,false,false]]}
false,true,false,false,false
{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible"]}
{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible",[false,true,false,false,false]]}
false,false,true,false,false
{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible"]}
{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible",[false,false,true,false,false]]}
false,false,false,true,false
{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible"]}
{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible",[false,false,false,true,false]]}
false,false,false,false,true
{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible"]}
{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible",[false,false,false,false,true]]}

[{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible",[]]},{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible",[]]},{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible",[]]},{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible",[]]},{"op1":true,"op2":false,"args":["visible",[]]}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide details of what the expected output is and what exactly is 'going missing'. You will get more accurate answers more quickly with a clear description of both the goal and the problem

Comment: `options.args.push(args_arr);` - you are pushing the _reference_ to `args_arr` into your args array here - so all of them refer to the _same_ array afterwards. Make that `options.args.push(Array.from(args_arr));` instead (`Array.from` to create a "clone" of the array), and check what you get then.

Comment: Don't write code this way unless the profiler tells you that you need to (and if you don't know what that means, you don't need to). Your future self will thank you. Separate out the creation of the arrays, the creations of the options objects, and formatting for display, instead of trying to do it all inline in a single loop.

Comment: So for every loop of j, I create a new set of args_arr from the i loop and then add them to options.args. This options is then added to options_arr but the true/false array goes missing in the final options array. I need this final options_arr as an descriptor for menus, so this format is important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you push the `args_arr` into the `options_arr` and modify the info afterwards.

Change `options.args.push(args_arr);` to `options.args.push([...args_arr]);`

What it will do is copy the values from args_arr into a new array. This way it will not reset on every loop.

Comment: But I need to reset args_arr every loop. For every loop I create a options with different args, which is then added to the options_arr

Comment: I added the ... but I have no idea why that worked. Thanx

Comment: The ... is the spread operator, it adds the elements one by one instead of the array itself. It's like doing args_arr[0], args_arr[1], args_arr[2]. etc..

Answer (score 0):

You need a new args_arr per loop

```js
const options_arr = [];
let options = '';
let text = [];
let args_arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    if (i === j) {
      args_arr.push(true);
    } else {
      args_arr.push(false);
    }
  }
  text.push(args_arr);
  let options = {
    op1: true,
    op2: false,
    args: ['visible']
  };
  options.args.push(args_arr);
  text.push(JSON.stringify(options))
  options_arr.push(options);
  args_arr = [];
}
text.push('<hr/>')
text.push(JSON.stringify(options_arr,null,2))

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text.join('<br/>');
```

```html
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really clear what you want to do. but you may clean your code. it will help realise the issue.

```
const options_arr=[];

let text = "";
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let options={
      op1:true,
      op2:false,
      args:['visible',[]]
  };
  for (let j=0;j<5;j++)
   options.args[1].push(i===j);
  options_arr.push(options);
}
text += JSON.stringify(options_arr) ;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the spread operator while pushing args_arr into `options.args` array, like this:

`options.args.push(...args_arr);`